# How to Iterate through a 2D array step by step using a button?

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I have to iterate through a 2D loop step by step after pressing a button in android, lets say

`3 4 3
 4 5 4
 2 3 4`

Output should be:

`After Button pressed:3
 After Button pressed:4
 After Button pressed:3
 .......
 .......
 After Button pressed:4`

How should I use clicklistener in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
int[][] array = new int[][]{
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
};

int rows = 0;
int columns = 0;
TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);


    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (columns < array[rows].length) {
                textView.setText("After Button pressed: " + array[rows][columns]);
                columns++;
            } else {
                rows++;
                if (rows != array.length) {
                    columns = 0;
                    textView.setText("After Button pressed: " + array[rows][columns]);
                    columns++;
                } else {
                    rows = 0;
                    columns = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: worked as expected. I was thinking about using two for loops and that created confusion for me